# Does Azure Data Lake Store support Kerberos/LDAP/SSO authentication?

Tags: azure, active-directory, ldap, kerberos, azure-data-lake

Considering that Azure Data Lake Store uses Active Directory for Authentication(which is inherently using Kerberos and LDAP), is there a way to directly use Kerberos, LDAP or SSO for Authentication with ADLS.

Scoured many documents including [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lakes-store-authentication-using-azure-active-directory) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-security-overview) but discovered that both Authentication mechanisms for ADLS use Active Directory - tenantid, clientid and client secret.

If not the above three, how many Authentication types does ADLS support?

Comment: To use Kerberos etc. wouldn't the Data Lake Store servers need to be domain-joined? And that is not happening.

Comment: What if we are able to connect using Azure Active Directory as described in : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-overview#azure-ad-domain-services-for-cloud-only-organizations

Answer (score 3):

Azure Data Lake Store (ADLS) uses Azure Active Directory. This is based on OAuth and completely different from Kerberos, LDAP, etc.

So the answer is no, ADLS does only support Azure AD.